# Dropdownlist2 Does not change the textBox value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to change my textbox after selecting dropdownlist2 textbox changes when i select dropdown1 but not on dropdown2, i mean i want textBox9 change when i select the dropdown2 list items

here is my code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;

namespace StackOver
{

   // public  string name2,name1;
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadOptions();
                //D;opDownList2.Visible=false;
                //]]]DropDownList2. = "0" 
                //LoadOptions1();
            }
        }
        protected void LoadOptions()
        {

            DataTable CardCode = new DataTable();
            string id, name, newName, name2;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=1.2.3.5;Initial Catalog=asdasd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=asdfgh");
            using (connection)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName from ocrd T1 ", connection);
                adapter.Fill(CardCode);

                if (CardCode.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < CardCode.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        id = CardCode.Rows[i]["CardCode"].ToString();
                        name = CardCode.Rows[i]["CardName"].ToString();
                        newName = id + " ---- " + name;

                        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(newName, id));

                        //DropDownList2.DataSource = CardCode;
                        //DropDownList2.DataValueField = "CardCode";
                        //DropDownList2.DataTextField = "CntctPrsn";
                        //DropDownList2.DataBind();

                    }
                }
                // adapter.Fill(CardCode);
                //DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CardCode";
                //DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CardCode";
                //DropDownList1.DataBind();

            }
        }



        protected void LoadOptions1()
        {

            DataTable CardCode = new DataTable();
            // string name2;
            string id, name, newName;
            string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
               SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=1.2.3.5;Initial Catalog=asdasd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=asdfgh");
            using (connection)
            {

                //SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName, T2.OpprId, T1.CntctPrsn,T2.CprCode,T3.CntctCode,T3.Name  FROM OCRD T1 left  join OOPR T2 on T1.CardCode=T2.CardCode left join OCPR T3 on T2.CprCode=T3.CntctCode where T1.CardCode=@CardCode ", connection);

                SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("Select Name,CntctCode from OCPR where CardCode=@CardCode ", connection);

                //  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName, T2.OpprId,T1.CntctPrsn, T2.CprCode,T2.MaxSumLoc  FROM OCRD T1 left  join OOPR T2 on T1.CardCode=T2.CardCode where T1.CardCode=@selected", connection);

                //   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName, T2.OpprId,T1.CntctPrsn, T2.CprCode,T2.MaxSumLoc  FROM OCRD T1 left  join OOPR T2 on T1.CardCode=T2.CardCode where T1.CardCode=@selected", connection);




                theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardCode", selected);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(theCommand);
                //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(CardCode);







                //name2 = id;

                if (CardCode.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < CardCode.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                     string name2 = CardCode.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                     string contcode = CardCode.Rows[i]["CntctCode"].ToString();
                     string newName2 = contcode + " ---- " + name2;

                        DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(newName2, contcode));




                        //DropDownList2.DataSource = CardCode;
                        //DropDownList2.DataValueField = "CardCode";
                        //DropDownList2.DataTextField = "CntctPrsn";
                        //DropDownList2.DataBind();

                    }


                }
            }
        }

        protected void LoadOptions2()
        {

            DataTable OprId = new DataTable();
            string id, name, newName, name2;
            string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
               SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=1.2.3.5;Initial Catalog=asdasd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=asdfgh");
            using (connection)
            {

                connection.Open();
                //SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName, T2.OpprId, T1.CntctPrsn,T2.CprCode,T3.CntctCode,T3.Name  FROM OCRD T1 left  join OOPR T2 on T1.CardCode=T2.CardCode left join OCPR T3 on T2.CprCode=T3.CntctCode where T1.CardCode=@CardCode ", connection);

                //SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("select max(T1.OpprId)+1 from OOPR T1 ", connection);

                SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("select max(T1.OpprId)+1 as OpprId from OOPR T1;", connection);
                theCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName, T2.OpprId,T1.CntctPrsn, T2.CprCode,T2.MaxSumLoc  FROM OCRD T1 left  join OOPR T2 on T1.CardCode=T2.CardCode where T1.CardCode=@selected", connection);
                theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpprId", TextBox8.Text);
                SqlDataReader theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (theReader.Read())
                {
                    this.TextBox8.Text = theReader["OpprId"].ToString();

                }
                //theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardCode", selected);

                //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                // adapter.Fill(CardCode);




                connection.Close();


                //name2 = id;


            }
        }


        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Clear();

            string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
            // string selected2 = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
            DropDownList2.Visible = true;
            //  DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value ="";
            LoadOptions1();
            //LoadOptions2();
              SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=1.2.3.5;Initial Catalog=asdasd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=asdfgh");
            using (connection)
            {
                // SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT CardCode, CardName, OpprId, CprCode,MaxSumLoc  FROM OOPR WHERE CardCode = @CardCode", connection);

                //  SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName, T2.OpprId, T1.CntctPrsn,T2.CprCode,T3.CntctCode,T3.Name  FROM OCRD T1 left  join OOPR T2 on T1.CardCode=T2.CardCode left join OCPR T3 on T2.CprCode=T3.CntctCode where T1.CardCode=@CardCode ", connection);

                SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName,T3.CntctCode,T3.Name  FROM OCRD T1 inner join OCPR T3 on T1.CardCode=T3.CardCode where T3.CardCode=@CardCode ", connection);


                connection.Open();

                theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardCode", selected);

                theCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //    DropDownList2.SelectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                SqlDataReader theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (theReader.Read())
                {
                    // Get the first row
                    // theReader.Read();

                    // Set the text box values
                    this.TextBox1.Text = theReader["CardCode"].ToString();
                    this.TextBox2.Text = theReader["CardName"].ToString();
                    //   this.TextBox5.Text = theReader["CprCode"].ToString();
                    // this.TextBox8.Text = theReader["OpprId"].ToString();
                    this.TextBox9.Text = theReader["CntctCode"].ToString();
                    //this.DropDownList2.SelectedValue = selected;
                    //this.DropDownList2.Text = theReader["CntctPrsn"].ToString();
                    // this.DropDownList2. = selected; 
                    this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value = selected;
                   //  this.TextBox4.Text = theReader["CntctCode"].ToString();

                    //   this.TextBox3 = reader.IsDBNull(TextBox3Index) ? null : reader.GetInt32(TextBox3Index)
                    // GenreID = reader.IsDBNull(genreIDIndex) ? null : reader.GetInt32(genreIDIndex)
                    // this.TextBox4.Text = theReader.GetString(3);
                    //  TextBox5.Text = theReader.GetString(4);
                    //  TextBox6.Text = theReader.GetString(5);
                    //  TextBox7.Text = theReader.GetString(6);

                }

                connection.Close();
            }

        }



        public object TextBox3Index { get; set; }


        //       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //    {
        //        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        //        connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDataBaseConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
        //        connection.Open();
        //        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        //        cmd.CommandText = "select * from  OOPR";
        //        cmd.Connection = connection;
        //        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        //        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        //        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //        da.Fill(ds, " OOPR");
        //        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        //        DataRow drow = ds.Tables["OOPR"].NewRow();
        //        drow["CardCode"] = TextBox1.Text;
        //        drow["CardName"] = TextBox2.Text;
        //        drow["OpprId"] = TextBox3.Text;
        //        drow["CprCode"] = TextBox4.Text;
        //        drow["MaxSumLoc"] = TextBox5.Text;

        //        ds.Tables["OOPR"].Rows.Add(drow);
        //        da.Update(ds, " OOPR ");
        //        string script = @"<script language=""javascript"">
        //        alert('Information have been Saved Successfully.......!!!!!.');
        //       </script>;";
        //        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script);
        //    }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=1.2.3.5;Initial Catalog=asdasd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=asdfgh");
            using (connection)
            {
                // connection.Open();
                //    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert into  OOPR(CardCode, CardName, OpprId, CprCode,MaxSumLoc) values (@TextBox1,@TextBox2,@TextBox8,@TextBox4,@TextBox5  )", connection); //('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "')", connection);

                SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert into  OOPR(CardCode, CardName, OpprId) values (@TextBox1,@TextBox2,@TextBox8  )", connection); //('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "')", connection);

                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox1", TextBox1.Text);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox2", TextBox2.Text);
                //  insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox3", TextBox3.Text);
             //   insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox4", TextBox4.Text);
                //  insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox5", TextBox5.Text);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox8", TextBox8.Text);


                connection.Open();
                // connection.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
                // connection.commandType=CommandType.Text;
                //  try
                //  {
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                //   }
                //catch
                //{
                //    TextBox5.Text = "Error when saving on database";
                //    connection.Close();
                //}
                //TextBox1.Text="";
                //TextBox2.Text = "";
                //TextBox3.Text = "";
                //TextBox4.Text="";
            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
            //    this.close();
        }

        protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
            LoadOptions1();

            string selected2 = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
            DropDownList2.Visible = true;
            //  DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value ="";

            //LoadOptions2();
              SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=1.2.3.5;Initial Catalog=asdasd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=asdfgh");
            using (connection)
            {
                // SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT CardCode, CardName, OpprId, CprCode,MaxSumLoc  FROM OOPR WHERE CardCode = @CardCode", connection);

                //  SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT T1.CardCode , T1.CardName, T2.OpprId, T1.CntctPrsn,T2.CprCode,T3.CntctCode,T3.Name  FROM OCRD T1 left  join OOPR T2 on T1.CardCode=T2.CardCode left join OCPR T3 on T2.CprCode=T3.CntctCode where T1.CardCode=@CardCode ", connection);

                SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT T3.CntctCode,T3.Name  FROM OCRD T1 inner join OCPR T3 on T1.CardCode=T3.CardCode where T3.CntctCode=@CntctCode", connection);


                connection.Open();

               theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CntctCode", selected2);
              theCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //    DropDownList2.SelectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                SqlDataReader theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (theReader.Read())
                {
                    // Get the first row
                    // theReader.Read();

                    // Set the text box values
                    //this.TextBox1.Text = theReader["CardCode"].ToString();
                    //this.TextBox2.Text = theReader["CardName"].ToString();
                    //   this.TextBox5.Text = theReader["CprCode"].ToString();
                    //  this.TextBox3.Text = theReader["OpprId"].ToString();
                    this.TextBox9.Text = theReader["CntctCode"].ToString();
                    //this.DropDownList2.SelectedValue = selected;
                    //this.DropDownList2.Text = theReader["CntctPrsn"].ToString();
                    // this.DropDownList2. = selected; 
                   this.DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value = selected2;

                    //   this.TextBox3 = reader.IsDBNull(TextBox3Index) ? null : reader.GetInt32(TextBox3Index)
                    // GenreID = reader.IsDBNull(genreIDIndex) ? null : reader.GetInt32(genreIDIndex)
                    // this.TextBox4.Text = theReader.GetString(3);
                    //  TextBox5.Text = theReader.GetString(4);
                    //  TextBox6.Text = theReader.GetString(5);
                    //  TextBox7.Text = theReader.GetString(6);

                }

                connection.Close();
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Instead of handling events (which are normally triggered by the user) you should provide methods. Then you can call these methods from both events.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is**, you're removing the `items` from `DropDownList2` in its event hadnler and then re-bind the items by calling method `LoadOptions1()`. This removing and re-binding removes the selected index of `DropDownList2`. So in short you have no value selected in `DropDownList2`.

**You should** do this re-binding in `DropDownList1` event handler, instead of doing it in `DropDownList2`.

Your code is fine just remove these lines from the handler `DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();       //remove
    LoadOptions1();                    //remove

    string selected2 = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
    DropDownList2.Visible = true;      //remove
    //...
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir its still not working :( kindly help

Comment: You need to describe the working with a little more detail. What is the work flow? When `DropDownList2` should be updated?

Comment: dear first i select the drop down list 1 and after selecting list 1 there is automaticaly fill all the textbox and update the dropdownlist2 but when i select dropdownlist2 there are no changing in textbox9 i want the change textbox9 with selecting dropdownlist2

Comment: I would still say you need to remove these 2 lines I mentioned from the handler `DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged`. They are not letting you get the value from `DropDownList2`.